# How to give aws credentials to minikube cluster

Tags: amazon-iam, minikube

I am running minikube local.
I created a job in which it will use boto3 to download the files from s3 and process them.
The boto3 code is

```
def get_bucket():
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
    assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
                                                RoleArn=role_arn,
                                                RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
                                            )
    credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']
    s3=boto3.resource(
                                's3',
                                aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
                                aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
                                aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
    )
    bucket = s3.Bucket(name=bucket_name)
    return bucket
```

before running the script I wrote

```
aws configure import --csv file://my-credsfile
```

my-credsfile contains

```
User Name,Access key ID,Secret access key
default,....,....
```

in .sh file which my docker image runs. **When I am just using docker. The container is running and able to download.** But When I am using it in Kubernetes. I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_data_from_s3.py", line 36, in <module>
    bucket=get_bucket()
  File "get_data_from_s3.py", line 9, in get_bucket
    assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 508, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 915, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: **userarn** is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: **role**
```

I also tried other way which is used as one option when we want to have ebs access to cluster.[in installation step](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/master/docs/install.md) by creating a secret in the kube-system namespace.

```
kubectl create secret generic aws-secret \
    --namespace kube-system \
    --from-literal "key_id=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}" \
    --from-literal "access_key=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}"
```

And removed the aws configure command from shell script. But now I am getting error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_data_from_s3.py", line 36, in <module>
    bucket=get_bucket()
  File "get_data_from_s3.py", line 9, in get_bucket
    assumed_role_object=sts_client.assume_role(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 508, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 898, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 921, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 119, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 198, in _send_request
    request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 134, in create_request
    self._event_emitter.emit(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 103, in handler
    return self.sign(operation_name, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 187, in sign
    auth.add_auth(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 407, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError()
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Even again I added credentials in docker cmd (shell script file) but again I am getting the first error (Access Denied error).

Answer (score 0):

During debugging I found that spaces are present at end of the variables, which were reading from secret. Now it is working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).